# Конкретный пример использования собственных векторов

Tags: математика, физика, численные-методы, линейная-алгебра

Хотелось бы увидеть пример использования в той же физике на конкретном примере.

В моем представлении это должно выглядеть как-то так: у нас есть `n` физических объектов с определенными свойствами, на основе этих свойств мы создаем матрицу `А`, находим собственные значения и собственные вектора.

На основе каких признаков может строиться матрица `А` (как мне кажется, это могут быть приложенные силы)? Ну хорошо, выполнил я этот шаг, а что мне дают собственные значения и вектора, где я их могу дальше использовать и для чего?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors#Applications